# Angular Universal SSR Azure Deployment Issue

Tags: azure, rendering, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, universal

I am having some issues with the Angular Universal when deploying on production. I am using the azure pipeline and the folder structure is like this.

[Like this ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw81T.png)

Now my issue is, that the site is working fine, but the HTML is still not being render in the page source. Is there any other step I need to do in order to populate the rendering of the html.

These are the step I am doing in the pipeline.

steps:

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install angular cli'
  inputs:
  command: custom
  verbose: false
  customCommand: 'install @angular/cli -g'
- task: Npm@0
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
  cwd: TasteUI
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install run build:ssr'
  inputs:
  command: custom
  workingDir: TasteUI
  verbose: false
  customCommand: 'run build:ssr'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'copy the server folder contents to a new dist folder copy'
  inputs:
  SourceFolder: TasteUI/dist/taste/server
  TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/taste/server'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'copy the server folder contents to a new dist folder copy copy'
  inputs:
  SourceFolder: TasteUI/dist/taste/browser
  TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/taste/browser'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy server.js to the root'
  inputs:
  SourceFolder: TasteUI/dist/taste/server
  Contents: main.js
  TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/taste'
  enabled: false
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Delete the dist/server.js'
  inputs:
  SourceFolder: TasteUI/dist/taste/server
  Contents: server.js
  RemoveSourceFolder: true
  enabled: false
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
  command: restore
  projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
  projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
  arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet Publish'
  inputs:
  command: publish
  publishWebProjects: True
  arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/taste/browser'
  zipAfterPublish: false
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/taste'
  inputs:
  rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/taste'
  includeRootFolder: false
  archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/taste.zip'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
  PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  ArtifactName: taste
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

Comment: Are you using @angular/pwa?

Comment: No.. what is it exactly?

Comment: Oh no never mind. I you were to be using @angular/pwa it would explain what you're experiencing.

Comment: Ah are you also deploying the `node_modules` folder to the server? As far as I can see not. You need this on the server too if you're using SSR instead of prerendering.

Comment: But to generate the node_modules I am doing the npm install right?

Comment: Yes that's correct